# Galois field problem in Cryptography

Tags: finite-field, group-theory

This problem is related to Fields in Cryptography, My Question is why there is no multiplicative inverse for 2, isn't it 0.5?? or matters are diffrent if it was related to galois field ? I don't quite understand.

**This is the Addition Tabel...**
[image]

**This Is the Multiplication Tabel...**
[image]

**And this is the tabel with the additive and multiplicative inverse that i have a problem with....**
[image]

Comment: $\mathbb Z_8$ is not a field. It's a ring denoted as $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$. All elements in a ring need not have multiplicative inverses. 

Only the elements $\{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ are invertible. 

The elements of $\mathbb Z_8$ are $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ - $0.5$ is not part of $\mathbb Z_8$.


$\mathbb F_{2^3}$ on the other hand is a field & $\mathbb F_{2^3}$ is not $\bmod 8$, it's modulo an irreducible polynomial like $t^3 + t + 1$ - i.e. $\bmod t^3 + t + 1$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a misunderstanding about discrete math specifically ring & field theory.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment, $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not a field, and thus not every element has a multiplicative inverse.

In general $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a field if and only if $m$ is a prime.

If $m$ is not a prime, then $m=pq,$ where $p,q$ are integers satisfying $1<p,q<m.$ If you pick $a$ which is divisible by $p,$ say, then $a=pk,$ for some integer $k\geq 1,$ and thus $qa=kpq=km$ is divisible by $m,$ which means
$qa\equiv 0 \pmod m.$